# Is there an STC for converting the Continental O-470-R to a fuel injected engine?

Tags: piston-engine, stc

Is there an STC for converting the Continental O-470-R to a fuel injected engine without making any other changes?

Comment: Welcome to the site @ETHEL. You need to add a bit more detail to your question, are you asking about mechanical fuel injection, or electronic fuel injection with a FADEC? When you say 'no other changes' what do you mean?

Comment: I’m not aware of an STC to change *any* engine from carbureted to fuel injected, but there may be an STC to swap the entire engine for a new fuel injected one, and you would trade in the old one or sell it yourself.

Comment: Maybe the broader question would be more interesting, is converting an engine from carbureted to fuel injected, something than has ever been approved via an STC?  My hunch is that this would be too much of a change to an engine to be worthwhile, and that swapping the whole thing out is the route you'd have to go. But it'd be interesting to see if there are any counter-examples.

Comment: GdD: Mechanical like Bendix and I was thinking about Pponk conversion.

Comment: StephenS: Yes could be one option and probably the easiest way.

Comment: RalphJ: Didn't think that a conversion like that would be that big. If it is, you are of course right. Have not read the Specs for the IO470 to see the difference, if there are any. I will do that.